# Bookmark consecutive lines that start with a number

Tags: notepad++

I want to bookmark consecutive lines that start with a number in Notepad++ with regex
for example, if my list is the following:

```
ABC
1,234,543
DFGHH
1234
HRHYTTJ
JTJYMYUY
1,456
23,567
hhtyjtyj
43,679
1969Q3
```

I need a regex that bookmarks the following in the above list:

```
1,456
23,567
```

The following regex works well:

```
^\d+.*\R(\d+.*)$
```

but it has a problem, it bookmark quarter lines in my list too! and I don't like this.
I tried the following regex but it is not working:

```
^(?!\d{4}Q[1-4])[^\d+.*\R(\d+.*)$]+
```

where is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following regex.

```
(?:^|\R)\K\d+(?:,\d+)*\R\d+(?:,\d+)*(?=\R)
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above regex.

```
(?:^|\R)         ## In a non-capturing group matching starting of a line OR \R here.
\K               ## \K is used to make sure previous match is done by don't consider it while printing/highlighting values.
\d+(?:,\d+)*\R   ## Matching 1 or more digits following by an optional non-capturing group which has comma followed by digits; then non-capturing group is followed by \R.
\d+(?:,\d+)*     ## Matching 1 or more digits following by an optional non-capturing group which has comma followed by digits
(?=\R)           ## Using positive look ahead to check if its followed by \R.
```

Comment: working good - please tell which section of your regex is matching quarter lines?

Comment: @PubgMobile, sure I have added details explanation, please do check and let me know if its not clear.

Answer (score 3):

In Notepad++ you can use:

```
^\d+(?:,\d+)*\R\d+(?:,\d+)*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\d+(?:,\d+)*` Match 1+ digits and optionally repeat `,` and 1+ digits
- `\R` Match any Unicode newline sequence
- `\d+(?:,\d+)*` Match 1+ digits and optionally repeat `,` and 1+ digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JYKTDz/1)

If you want to match 2 or more consecutive lines, you can repeat the whole second part 1 or more times:

```
^\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\R\d+(?:,\d+)*)+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kDDA9w/1)